# plotly - how to show the highest value of an axis as 0

Tags: python, plotly

How can I set the intersection between the y axis and the x axis at some value of y, instead of (0,0)?
On the y axis I have a percentage and it's shown in this way: starting at zero and decreasing.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiAHB.png)
I want to have positive values on the y axis, which maximum value is zero and increase as you approach the intersection with the x axis, like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56eJj.png)

Comment: To reverse the y-axis, try the following. `fig.update_yaxes(autorange="reversed")` See this for [details](https://plotly.com/python/axes/#reversed-axes).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.